# How to draw dashed line using html and css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How to draw dashed line using html and css as below. Not the dotted line.

"--------------------------------------------------"

Can use this border: 1px dashed. 
But need to increase the length size of the dash.not the width

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) and you can control size and spacing like you want:

```css
.line {
  margin:5px 0;
  height:2px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,red 0 5px,#0000 0 7px)
    /*5px red then 2px transparent -> repeat this!*/
}

.line1 {
  margin:5px 0;
  height:2px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,red 0 3px,#0000 0 7px)
    /*3px red then 4px transparent -> repeat this!*/
}

.line2 {
  margin:5px 0;
  height:2px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,red 0 10px,#0000 0 12px)
    /*10px red then 2px transparent -> repeat this!*/
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line1"></div>
<div class="line2"></div>
```

You can also have all of them in the same element using multiple background:

```css
.line {
  margin:5px 0;
  height:20px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,red 0 5px ,#0000 0 7px) top,
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,red 0 3px ,#0000 0 7px) center,
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,red 0 10px,#0000 0 12px) bottom;
  background-size:100% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: This one draws line like this _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ >. I want to append arrow after this like below..  ------------------------------------>. But using above line that cannot create.

Comment: @SSSS adjust the backround position ... as you can see in may last code, the height is 20px and there is a gradient in the middle ... so adjust the height you want and place the gradient in the middle

Comment: this is the arrow used. fa ui-icon-keyboard-arrow-right